# File is Attached or not in File field?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I have the following code:

```
if (formItems != null && formItems.size() > 0) {
    // iterates over form's fields
    for (FileItem item : formItems) {
        // processes only fields that are not form fields
        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
            String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
            File storeFile = new File(filePath);

            // saves the file on disk
            item.write(storeFile);
            session.setAttribute("image", fileName);
        }
        // processes only form fields
        else {
            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
            String fieldvalue = item.getString();
            session.setAttribute(fieldname, fieldvalue);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to check a file is attached or not first. If attached then only upload the file. I have tried this:

```
if(item==null)
```

But this won't work. How can I check if a file attached or not? I have a file field:

```
<input type="file" name="image"/>
```

Comment: Do you have the `enctype` proper?

Comment: yes.  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `item` is never `null`.

Just check if the `FileItem#getName()` (the file name) is empty and/or `FileItem#getSize()` (the file size) equals to `0`.

In your particular case, with an `<input type="file" name="image"/>`, that'll be :

```
if (!item.isFormField()) {
    if ("image".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
        if (item.getName() == null || item.getName().isEmpty()) {
            // No file was been selected.
        }

        if (item.getSize() == 0) {
            // No file was been selected, or it was an empty file.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was finding from a long time but i can't got the answer. But how the file field name is directly access?

Comment: That's just conform `multipart/form-data` encoding specification. This is by the way also the case in default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, the input field names are always present as request parameter names, but they can be submitted as empty, this is recognizable by the value being submitted as empty string instead of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check whether your fileupload control has any value. `filename` is the name of my fileupload control

```
if ("filename".equals(item.getFieldName()) && item.getSize() > 0) {
    // your code here
} else {
    // Exception handling as no file chosen/attached
}
```

Comment: You may want to format your answer to differentiate between code and the text: "You can use below code to check whether your fileupload control("filename" in my case) has any value"

Comment: @Lincoln: Sure. Will look upon this suggestion . Thank you

Comment: @BalusC I have recently started working on some old version project and so coming through these issues now. Also, being unable to vote due to reputations, i have tried to make the code look short, simple and crisp through my answer.

Comment: I agree with your answer totally. Please consider it as a simplification to your answer as all the conditions kinda created confusion while looking at it for the first time . Thanks anyway!